# What does the word "pass" really mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

Philanderer is someone who makes love insincerely, someone who engages in passing love affairs.

NB I looked it up in dictionaries but there was no thing such as "pass love affair" in non of them. Does it mean ongoing ? or de facto?

Answer (score 3):

*Passing* in this context is an adjective meaning transient and not long-lasting.

Comment: ahlan wa sahlan.

Comment: "Two ships that pass in the night" but with a little colliding.